# Visual Studio 2010 & html entities?

Tags: html, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I'm trying to insert a `&raqou;` (») in a page in my VS2010 but it isn't recognized. Is there a way for this alias to be recognized or am I forced to use `&#187;`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is `&raquo;`